# Form Not Redirecting After Submit Header Location in PHP Not Working

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

My PHP header redirection isn't working and I can't seem to figure out why. I've read through a lot of questions and nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
<?php
define('DBHOST','shareddb1d.hosting.stackcp.net');
define('DBUSER','JoplinLeftHand-3231135a');
define('DBPASS','Banoodle1!');
define('DBNAME','JoplinLeftHand-3231135a');

$link = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);

if (!link) {
    die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "You Are Connected<br>";
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t Use ' . DBNAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Database Selected";
}
$tid = $_POST['tid'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$descrip = $_POST['descrip'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tracking (tracking_id, tracking_first, tracking_last, tracking_zip, tracking_descrip) VALUES ('$tid', '$first', '$last', '$zip', '$descrip')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header("Location:/?p5");
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this. mysql_* functions are deprecated, you need to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header('Location: ...');` has to be the first output of the script, otherwise it will not work. You are using `echo` twice before performing the redirect, here:

```
echo "You Are Connected<br>";
```

and here:

```
echo "Database Selected";
```

Also, SOME clients require the URL passed in the `Location` header to be absolute URLs, and not relative, for example:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/?p5");
```

Comment: Thank you. That was definitely the issue.